# At what point does a controller class instantiate a controller object in a Rails web app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, object, object-lifetime

Learning Rails, the point at which a controller gets instantiated is unclear to me whereas, the point at which a model gets instantiated is somewhat recognizable as for example, when a user enters data in a from and clicks the submit button is sort of a trigger that leads to a creation of an object model.

Done some research and I'm visualizing in my head that when a HTTP request is sent via the browser, the routing to a controller becomes the trigger to instantiate a certain controller object from a controller class.

Is this somewhat correct?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When the HTTP request enters your application server (puma, webrick, etc), the request passes through a stack of middleware (defined in `rails` gem), which converts the HTTP request into an instance of `ActionDispatch::Request` class which is used to determine the correct route to dispatch to appropriate controller class in your rails app based on the route definitions defined in `config/routes.rb`.

The generated `request` object is then dispatched to the corresponding controller and action method which instantiates the Controller class and invokes an action method on it's instance with an argument of `params` object (instance of `ActionController::Parameters`).

This is just a general overview of how Controllers are instantiated. The request object passes through a series of middleware classes and modules before a `request` object is generated.

Here's a good article if you want to [read it in detail](http://www.rubypigeon.com/posts/examining-internals-of-rails-request-response-cycle/).

Comment: Thank you very much! An explanation of a layer I have been looking for!!

Answer (score 0):

As we define the routes in routes.rb, than the control goes to that controller action at that time the controller get's initiated to work

Comment: I would like to see a lower layer explanation of where, what point and how a controller gets instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

It is more related to object oriented programming, The object is always instantiated when you call `new` on `class`

```
2.0.0-p648 :001 > Class.new
 => #<Class:0x007fee8e99d9a8> 
2.0.0-p648 :002 >
```

Here the object is instantiated, and similarly in rails when you call any action lets say

```
def new
  @article = Article.new
end
```

new object gets initiated, when you click on `save`, you are actually calling `create` action, and pass the current object.

```
def create
  @article = Article.create(article_params)
  @article.save
end
```

here `.create` method filled object with `article_params` and `.save` method saves object in database.

Comment: I understand how a model is getting instantiated but I would like to know how a controller gets instantiated.

Comment: When your application receives a request, the routing will determine which controller and action to run, then Rails creates an instance of that controller and runs the method with the same name as the action.